# SwiftUI Elements move down between views

Tags: swiftui

I have two views

```
    import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("qr-code")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .position(x: 100, y: 100)
                    .offset(x: 100)
                Text("Thank you")
                    .position(x: 200)
            }.toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Show QR")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: CustomizeView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Customize")
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomizeView: View {
    var body: some View {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                    Text("Task data goes here")
                    Text("Task data goes here")
                }
            }.toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Show QR")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: CustomizeView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Customize")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        
            CustomizeView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
            
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on Customize and the click on Show, I see that the picture moves down. Is it expected behavior? How can I make sure that all elements are in the same positions regardless of how much I clicked on nvaigation buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only have one `NavigationView` in your view hierarchy.

Right now, there are `NavigationView`s in `ContentView` and in `CustomizeView` any time you navigate to either with a `NavigationLink`, it will add an additional navigation bar to the view, pushing down your content.

To fix this, your root view could just be the `NavigationView` and then you links could navigation to views that do not contain additional `NavigationView`s.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            BasicView()
        }
    }
}

struct BasicView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .position(x: 100, y: 100)
                .offset(x: 100)
            Text("Thank you")
                .position(x: 200)
        }.toolbar{
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                NavigationLink(destination: BasicView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                    Text("Show QR")
                }
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: CustomizeView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                    Text("Customize")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomizeView: View {
    var body: some View {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                    Text("Task data goes here")
                    Text("Task data goes here")
                }
            }.toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: BasicView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Show QR")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: CustomizeView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
                        Text("Customize")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but it didn't work for me (I've updated my code)

Comment: See my update. Because you were navigating to `ContentView` again, it was adding another `NavigationView` to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, I think you have called another `ContentView` from a `ContentView`. That's why one more navigation bar is added and shifted

You can create another view called `QRShowView` and place the qr image there and you have already `CustomizeView` view . Add two buttons in `ContentView` like show or customized.

Then call the respective view when is clicked.